# Customized separated jquery only for dialog and for tabview

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, tabview

I want to use only dialog functionality on a page so I do not want to use entire jquery, because I want to reduce the content transfer while loading a page.

Same I want to do for some other page with dialog.

I want to load that pages on mobile, which is connected with WiFi router, if more people using the same router then transferring entire jquery may take more size. So want to reduce the size.

I am trying to split the specific functionality from the jquery but its taking difficulty. Can you suggest me the best way of doing the same?